# How can I download one file from different places

Tags: download

I want to download a file of large size ok?

It is on many servers but all servers are so slow, each link alone give me 10 KB/s but other fast downloads reach 130 KB/s.

I'm asking if there are any method or available software that can download one file from many places URLs at the same time???

Comment: What technology do you want to use to download the file?

Comment: There are many "download managers" that will allow you to do this.  Some free, some pay.  They all basically operate the same, but some have features other don't.  There are probably too many to list, you really need to search for download manager and see and try to see what you like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Free Download Manager](http://www.freedownloadmanager.org/)** offers this (amongst many other features):

**Simultaneous downloading from several mirrors**

> Free Download Manager is able to
>   download files from several mirrors
>   simultaneously.

**Download acceleration**

> Free Download Manager splits files
>   into several sections and downloads
>   them simultaneously, allowing you to
>   use any type of connection at the
>   maximum available speed. With FDM
>   download speed increases, or even
>   more!

*FDM is open source freeware.*

Answer (score 2):

Try e.g. GetRight, you can find it here: http://getright.com/

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly what [BitTorrent](http://www.bittorrent.com/) does. I would make a torrent and then have the many slow servers seed it.

Answer (score 1):

With [orbit downloader](http://www.orbitdownloader.com/) (freeware) you could add mirrors for simultaneous multi-parts download.
(It also have options to automatically search mirrors and to download from peers (orbitnet P2P) but from my experience they aren't really effective)